# How to extract values from a pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to using pandas and running into an issue when trying to extract values from a pivot table.

```
        pivot = sp.pivot_table(
            index="story_points",
            values=["duration"],
            aggfunc={"min", "mean", "median", "max", "count"},
        )
        df = pivot.iloc[:, "duration"]
        zero = df.iloc[0, "median"]
        one = df.iloc[1.0, "median"]
        two = df.iloc[2.0, "median"]
        three = df.iloc[3.0, "median"]
```

```
                    duration                                            
                    count         max       mean     median       min
story_points_raw                                                     
1.0                   227  185.125382   7.241453   2.190405  0.000139
2.0                   144   68.849965  11.048451   6.106875  0.000058
3.0                    45  126.131181  19.560792  13.558588  0.983241
4.0                    16   49.043889  11.948981   6.932321  1.878125
5.0                     5  128.653403  44.487847  15.489850  2.935891
8.0                     8   79.792199  31.325800  17.299543  7.774792
```

I get an error on the line `df = pivot.iloc[:, "duration"]`. Is there possibly a better way to create the table to allow easier direct access to the values?

Comment: You appear to have a multiindex, have you check the contents of `pivot.columns` to see what your actual columns are? You could possibly use a combination column name, like `df['duration','count']]` or you could use [droplevel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) to drop one level from your column multiindex

Comment: @pcdr Could you please provide the desired output?